# Remove write protection from files on a different partition

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, file-permissions

**Background:**

I have an installation of Windows 10 on my C: drive, that up until Friday was working perfectly. Then, suddenly I get blue screens (Registry error) whenever trying to boot. I have tried many things to fix it, but the short of it is no program is able to recognize the disk as containing a Windows installation, so most recovery tools dont work.

**Goal**:

I loaded another SSD into my computer, with a working copy of Windows 10. I would like to transfer my files from the C: drive installation to a backup disk.

**Problem**:

The files are write protected and I don't have the ability to view the folders.
When I try to enter a folder like `C:\Users\<username>` I get an error: "You don't currently have permission to access this folder". I tried using `takeown` and `icacls` to gain permission, but they did not work because the media is write protected. When I use diskparts to check the disk attributes here's what I get:

```
DISKPART> attributes disk
Current Read-only State : Yes
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No
```

The `Current Read-only State : Yes` concerns me. From what I've read this normally has to do with a physical switch which my SSD definitely does not have.

**Question**:

How can I modify the permissions of the files on the C: drive, given that I have access to the admin Microsoft account and that I am personally the owner of the files?

Comment: You don't need write permission to read.

Comment: What commands did you try? What errors did you get? Your assumption this failed *"because the media is write protected"* is unfounded.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor There are many files that I am unable to read, and in order to add read permissions to the files, it seems I need write permissions

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I've tried a lot of commands, I will edit the post to include more of what I've tried. The reason I think it's write protected is because when I use diskpart to list the attributes I get "Current Read-only state: True". Even though I am able to set "readonly" attribute to False.

Comment: That's good information to put into your question!

Comment: Write permission of file does not control permission to change permissions. The permissions to change permissions are: Ownership, and file system write status (the file-system needs to be writable, the one reported by disk parted). Thinks may be different on MS-Windows. They like to be different, and incompatible.

Comment: I see, so write permission might be the wrong word. I think my whole SSD isnt writable anymore